# Anker Astro E4 to power Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware

Looking for some help to be honest,  This is not my area of knoladge atall. 
Ive read around the question of powering my Pi with a battery,  now I nabbed one of these guys for my phone

http://www.amazon.co.uk/13000mAh-Portable-External-Technology-Motorola-Black/dp/B00BQ5KHJW/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1420826597&sr=1-1-catcorr&keywords=anker+astro+e4

Incase the link dies in the future;

```
Item model number: AK-79AN13K2-BA
Anker® 2nd Gen Astro E4 13000mAh 2-Port (3A Output) Fast 
Max 3A Out
5V Out
```

Now,  from what i've read there have been mixed notes of,  don't use batterys,  only use this battery,  don't do this,  don't exeed this magical number ( which was differant each time ).  so any help would be grately needed.  If i was to power my pi via this thing.  im I going to get a poof of smoke and need to replace the poor pi :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.  You might get better answers over at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A raspberry Pi is powered via USB, which means that it simply takes the 5V supplied via USB to run. As long as your current source is stable (ie. it doesn't change when you draw current from it), no device will care whether it is a battery or a switching power supply. Now, a bare raspberry Pi B uses less than 2W of power, 2W/5V = 0.4A = 400mA, so if that battery pack lives up to its specification, you are going to be fine. The device is spec'ed to provide 13000mAh, so at a constant current of 400mA, this would last you more than 32 hours.

Now, most people attach *something* to the raspberry, and that something will also draw power, but just add that power to the calculations above, to see if it's going to work out.